# NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, palm-api

while using Langchain and GooglePalm I am getting the following error in google Colab

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-5bd555f28cce> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 llm =GooglePalm(google_api_key=api_key)
      2 embeddings = GooglePalmEmbeddings(google_api_key=api_key)
      3 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain_core/_api/deprecation.py in warn_deprecated(since, message, name, alternative, pending, obj_type, addendum, removal)
    293         if not removal:
    294             removal = f"in {removal}" if removal else "within ?? minor releases"
--> 295             raise NotImplementedError(
    296                 f"Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. "
    297                 f"{removal}"

NotImplementedError: Need to determine which default deprecation schedule to use. within ?? minor releases
```

GooglePalmEmbeddings working fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnaC1.png)

what's wrong with it? Would anyone be able to help me resolve this? I used the same code earlier but only got an error today is there any change in the library